# Are these points known?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $P$ be a point on the plane, $PA$, $PB$, $PC$ meet $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ at $A'$, $B'$, $C'$ respectively.

From my construction by GeoGebra, I found two special points as follows:

> > In any triangle exist two points $P$ so that: $AA'+BC=BB'+CA=CC'+AB$.
>
> **My question:** What is name of the points? Or are the points known?

[image]

```
                             RED=GREEN=BLUE
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be among the 25000 centres listed here: http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html

Comment: I wrote the letter to asked Dr. Kimberling and some other. But they didn't  know. Dr.Kimberling http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/